# Unable to access Inner Interface of class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have an adapter class for recyclerview:

```
public abstract class RecyclerViewArrayAdapter<T, VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

        ...
  }
```

I am creating an object like this :

```
  new RecyclerViewArrayAdapter<String, ListImageItemViewHolder>(emailAddresses) {
            @Override
            public ListImageItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                return new ListImageItemViewHolder(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(ListImageItemViewHolder holder, int position) {


                holder.setClickListener(new ListImageItemViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick) {


                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

The ListImageItemViewHolder definition looks like this:

```
public class ListImageItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    private ClickListener clickListener;


    public ListImageItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick);
    }


   public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }
  }
```

Everything looks fine, no red mark, however as soon as I compile the following line gives me a n error;

> Error:(147, 68) error: cannot find symbol class ClickListener

Like 147 is :

```
holder.setClickListener(new ListImageItemViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick) {


                    }
                });
```

Question: Why it is not able access ClickListener .. .

It driving me crazy ?

What wrong am I doing here...

UPDATES:

I found that the issue is with minify.

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
}
}

The RecyclerViewArrayAdapter and ListImageItemViewHolder is the part of a module called "Common". I refer this module in my project.

Now when I have a common gradle set to "minify" to false it works. 
The moment I change it to minify true, it comes back.

It looks like a compilation issue. But I cannot live with this error nor I can set minify to false for the production build.

Can someone please help me with the work around ?

[image]

Comment: You can't call a interface you can implement one..

Comment: @VaibhavG I am implementing the same - please see new ListImageItemViewHolder.ClickListener() {  } line

Comment: @VaibhavG even if I declare I get this error   private ListImageItemViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener;

Comment: Make sure to add in the new proguard exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
new ListImageItemViewHolder().clickListener = new ClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick) {


                }
            });
```

This line  `new ListImageItemViewHolder().clickListener` refers to `ClickListener clickListener;`

Then you instantiate it..

Declare clickListener using access specifier **public**

Comment: Error:(147, 68) error: cannot find symbol class ClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is no solution as such but a work around. 
To me, it is nothing wrong with the code. There is no red line whatsoever but it cannot find when I compile. However, when I set minify to false then it works (even when the minify setting is set for release version and I am running as debug).

The solution is to separate out ClickListener interface away from  ListImageItemViewHolder class; thus no to nested interface.

```
 public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick);
    }
```