# Cannot access inner interface from a ProGuard-ed JAR

Tags: java, jar, proguard, inner-classes

I created a Java class with an inner interface like this:

```
public class TaskManager {
    // other codes

    public interface TaskManagerListener {
        void onLoad();
    }

    // other codes
}
```

Then I wrapped it inside a JAR using ProGuard for obfuscation/shrinking.
I used the following ProGuard configuration:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keep public class package.name.of.TaskManager { *; }
-keep public interface package.name.of.TaskManager$TaskManagerListener { *; }
```

I verified from the JAR that the class and the inner interface are there: 
[image: this image].

My problem now is when I try to access that inner interface from the code that uses the JAR. I can access the `TaskManager` class fine but the accessing `TaskManager.TaskManagerListener` raises a compile error.

These work:

1. `public class MyTaskManager extends TaskManager {..}`
2. `TaskManager tm = new TaskManager();`

But these do NOT:

1. `public class MyTaskManagerListener implements TaskManager.TaskManagerListener`
2. `new TaskManager.TaskManagerListener() {
       @Override
       public void onLoad() {..}
   });`

A **"Cannot resolve symbol TaskManagerListener"** error is raised.

I tried to access the `TaskManager.TaskManagerListener` from the original code of the JAR library and it's working OK. So I guess I only can't access it when it's inside a JAR..?

Is there a way to make this work?
Or is my expectation wrong?
I'm not sure if there's something missing from my ProGuard config or with my understanding of Java and inner interfaces.

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533243/unable-to-access-inner-interface-of-class) answer and I'm already considering the workaround to not use a nested interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a dumb mistake.
The ProGuard config that I used was actually correct, but another `keepattributes !InnerClasses` option was negating the config that I used (*apparently, the order of the `keepattributes` options does not really matter*).

This is still correct:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keep public class package.name.of.TaskManager { *; }
-keep public interface package.name.of.TaskManager$TaskManagerListener { *; }
```

Which will produce the obfuscated JAR below:

[image]

Which now makes these work:

1. `public class MyTaskManager extends TaskManager {..}`
2. `TaskManager tm = new TaskManager();`